# how download m3u8 in chunks using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert `m3u8` to `mp4` and I found the following method that works

```
ffmpeg -i 'https://....m3u8' -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \
    -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 output.mp4
```

The end result, however, is too big for me to drag into an external hard drive.

I also tried writing directly to the hard drive `/Volumes/2TR/output.mp4` but the end result is the same - the file is too big, the operation fails.

I noticed that if I terminate the operation at any point, the `output.mp4` file works perfectly, but that it's not the full video (perfect). If the video is one hour and I just want 30 minutes of it I can terminate the `ffmpeg` operation at that point.

So I'm wondering whether there's a way for `ffmpeg` to download the contents in two parts, `output-part1.mp4` and `output-part2.mp4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the segment muxer for this.

```
ffmpeg -i 'https://....m3u8' -c copy -f segment -segment_time 1800 output-part%d.mp4
```

This will split the output into segments of (nearly) 1800 seconds.

(`-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc` is automatically inserted by ffmpeg for a few years now. Your ffmpeg is too old if it's required.)

Comment: amazing! is it possibile to download a `segment_time` for end position?